# Cannot find namespace NodeJS when executing ng test / karma runner / protractor

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using Ionic2 and Ionic Serve command works fine (see below). Previews i had problems with @types/node but i did handle it chaining some inside code.

My settings of file **tsconfig.json**

```
    {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015"
    ],
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "typings/index.d.ts",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ],
  "typeRoots": [
    "../node_modules/@types"
  ],
  "types": [
    "jasmine",
    "node"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "src/test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "e2e",
    "www"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": true
  }
}
```

Log from Command line after **ionic serve** command.

```
    [INFO] Starting app-scripts server: --port 8100 --p 8100 --livereload-port 35729 --r 35729 --address 0.0.0.0 - Ctrl+C to cancel
[13:45:46]  watch started ...
[13:45:46]  build dev started ...
[13:45:46]  clean started ...
[13:45:46]  clean finished in 15 ms
[13:45:46]  copy started ...
[13:45:46]  transpile started ...
[13:45:52]  transpile finished in 6.16 s
[13:45:52]  preprocess started ...
[13:45:52]  deeplinks started ...
[13:45:52]  deeplinks finished in 266 ms
[13:45:52]  preprocess finished in 266 ms
[13:45:52]  webpack started ...
[13:45:53]  copy finished in 6.76 s
[13:46:05]  webpack finished in 13.09 s
[13:46:05]  sass started ...
[13:46:08]  sass finished in 2.78 s
[13:46:08]  postprocess started ...
[13:46:08]  postprocess finished in 15 ms
[13:46:08]  lint started ...
[13:46:09]  build dev finished in 23.17 s
[13:46:09]  watch ready in 23.61 s
[13:46:09]  dev server running: http://localhost:8100/
```

Wired is that i cannot perform any **test scenario** within the same project. I cannot load Nodejs namepsace.

```
WARNING in ./~/ionic-angular/util/ng-module-loader.js
54:11-36 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
WARNING in ./~/ionic-angular/util/ng-module-loader.js
69:11-36 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
WARNING in ./~/ajv/lib/async.js
119:15-28 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
ERROR in D:/Work/blabla/trunk/src/app/app.spec.ts (19,16): Supplied 
parameters do not match any signature of call target.

ERROR in D:/Work/blabla/trunk/src/view/components/login/login.spec.ts 
(36,45): Property 'name' does not exist on type 'LoginPage'.

ERROR in D:/Work/blabla/trunk/src/platform/model/usergroupmodel.ts (92,26): Argument of type 'UserGroupBlock' is not assignable to parameter of type 'boolean'.

ERROR in D:/Work/blabla/trunk/src/platform/presenter/presentersession.ts (29,26): Cannot find namespace 'NodeJS'.

ERROR in D:/Work/blabla/trunk/src/platform/engine/db/storagetable.ts (30,46): Parameter 'ctor' of constructor from exported class has or is using private name 'ItemConstructor'.

ERROR in D:/Work/blabla/trunk/src/platform/engine/bus/status.ts (56,9): Property 'tout' of exported interface has or is using private name 'NodeJS'.
D:/Work/blabla/trunk/src/platform/engine/bus/status.ts (56,9): Cannot find namespace 'NodeJS'.

ERROR in D:/Work/blabla/trunk/src/platform/presenter/presenters/usergroupspresenter.ts (43,24): Argument of type '"UserPresenter|User not found."' is not assignable to parameter of type 'boolean'.

ERROR in D:/Work/blabla/trunk/src/platform/presenter/presenter.ts (189,11): Parameter 'ctor' of constructor from exported class has or is using private name 'NoParamConstructor'.

ERROR in D:/Work/blabla/trunk/src/platform/engine/comm/commdiscovery.ts (7,21): Cannot find namespace 'NodeJS'.

ERROR in D:/Work/blabla/trunk/src/platform/engine/comm/websocks.ts (12,25): Cannot find namespace 'NodeJS'.
D:/Work/blabla/trunk/src/platform/engine/comm/websocks.ts (13,22): Cannot find namespace 'NodeJS'.
D:/Work/blabla/trunk/src/platform/engine/comm/websocks.ts (14,23): Cannot find namespace 'NodeJS'.
```